# RAID Card Event Notifications Email to Gmail

Tags: email, raid, smtp

I need to get email for event notifications from our RocketRaid 2782.

The problem is I don't see a way to get it to send mail to our google apps gmail account. I don't think the card offers authenticated email. Picture attached below:

[image: RocketRaid Email Menu]

I am prepared to install Postfix on the host computer the card is in, (Ubuntu Server 12.04.1) in the hopes that I can relay email from "unsecured" Card Source to "Secure" Gmail destination.

Can someone provide a solution? Can I configure the HighPoint to send to "localhost" and then configure Postfix to send that mail to Gmail but using the approved secure settings.

Full disclosure: I have never installed or used Postfix in my life EVER! Willing to learn ASAP though.  But any solution will need to have clear steps!

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure the card can reach the Internet and has valid name services?

Comment: Hey Keith, I believe so? I'm not sure if you mean the card itself or the computer the card is in? I can reach that computer as I am using ssh right now to control it (from another location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot clearly shows a login name and password field. That would be for authenticating to the SMTP server.

Comment: So, perhaps I could have elaborated more. But I have obviously tried using a username and password combo that i know works with gmail. The issue I believe comes with using port 25 or not using SSL or TCL or TLS etc. I have tried using the same user/pass combo using port 465 and 587, with no luck.

Comment: OK, I got it. Try configuring it to send to a gmail.com email address by using one of the MX records for gmail.com. Remove the Login Name information, set the server address to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, and set the recipient as one of your gmail.com addresses. This should approximate a user sending email to a gmail.com recipient, which should work. The way you're tring to configure it now is to use gmail.com to send email to any possible recipient which would require authentication, but sending to a gmail.com recipient shouldn't.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I've been researching, I basically need an internal relay agent like hMailServer but for Ubuntu. Something like this guide: [link](http://www.g-asiapac.com/Google-Apps-Malaysia/setup-internal-smtp-relay-server). But that can be applied to an Ubuntu environment.  This card is the same as an old printer or scanner etc that cannot use TLS or SSL auth. Hence it MUST have a relay in between.

Comment: Turns out it did work. I had not saved the config to the card before trying a test email.

Comment: Glad you got it working.